# v-model overwrite input value in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have this input

```
<input type="text" :value="user.firstName" v-model="userInfo.firstName">
```

that is in a component edit.vue.

In users.vue I have router link

```
<router-link :to="'/users/edit-user/'+user.id"><a>Edit</a></router-link>
```

and when I click it takes me on edit component with the id of the actual user on url.

The problem is that if I put this `v-model="userInfo.firstName"` in that first input overwrites the data that I bring to edit it, the name.

If I delete this `v-model="userInfo.firstName"` from that input I can see the actual value of the input, that comes from database, I mean the actual name.

I need this  v-model, in that edit page, to take the new input value and send it back to database.

In a normal edit, when you click on edit button, you suppose to see the actual data to edit it, not an empty input.

So why v-model overwrites that user.name value(that comes from a json users, from database) and what can I do to make a see the actual value and be able to send the modified value input in database?

Answer (score 4):

`v-model` overrides the value property, so you can't use both on the same component. You should use only v-model and just set `userInfo.name = user.name` when the component is created:

```
created (){
 this.userInfo.name = this.user.name
}
```

Comment: ok I understand, but if put what you said in my code, the input in the edit page is still empty even in the url I see `users/edit-user/48`. I initialize user in data and set it up on the method that brings the specific user: ``` getUsers() {
        this.$http.get('/user/' + this.$route.params.id)
          .then((response) => {
            this.user = response.data;
          })
      }```

Comment: and the userInfo is the same in data: userInfo: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          phone: '',
          idCard: '',
          departmentId: 1,
          function: '',
          jobTitle: '',
          cityId: '',
          countryId: '',
          userTypeId: 1
        } and used in the put method:  axios.put('/user/' + this.$route.params.id, this.userInfo)

Comment: please post the components so i can see what you're doing